# Google Maps can't get my location right after setup map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

When my app starts, it loads a map right in the first screen.
Right after setting up the `GoogleMap`, I'd like to access `googleMap.getMyLocation()` and use the location to center the map.

The problem is that the method is returning `null` rather than the actual user location.
I believe that's because there was not enough time for the map gather the necessary data and make it available. I say that because if I wait a while and use a button to change the map center, the location returned is a valid value.

Is there a non-blocking way to poll that method and update the map as soon as a location is available?

Also, I just noticed that the method `getMyLocation()` has been annotated as Deprecated. Is there any new way to get the location?

Comment: Regarding location: Have you heard of the Fused location provider? I think it's the best (and newest) way.  It intelligently manages the underlying location technology (sensors) http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html... And here the official presentation in Google IO https://developers.google.com/live/shows/518756499

Comment: Is it the Android's "stock" location services? If so, earlier today I replaced some of that stuff with Google Maps API methods. Was that a bad decision?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "stock", but it's supposed to be the way to go. It combines location provided by , GPS, cell-towers,wifi,even accelerometer and gyros (for improvements while indoor), etc. and gives you the best available when you request it.

Comment: I mean that it's not an additional library that provides these services. Even though it needs Google Play Services, it feels like a standard, not a 3rd party library. Thanks for the hint. It doesn't actually answer the question, but I believe it solves my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Location, as I said in my comment, the new approach is using [Fused Location Provider](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). It allows you to obtain the best available location obtained by a combination of all your sensors (GPS, wifi, cell towers and other sensors(for indoors).

Also, since this location is already obtained before you run your app, you wouldn't have to wait at start time of the app. If you call

```
Location mCurrentLocation;
mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
```

It would give you the most recent location.

You can also request timed updates if you want to keep centering the map as you move.

To start trying this, I would recommend this 'getting started' site and to download the sample project listed in the right of this website: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the location from the os.  Then to position the map use code similar to this.
I was never able to get the Location and LatLng classes to cast so I do this manually.

```
if (location != null) {
     LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```